# How to remove Mimikatz from recycling bin?

Tags: windows, permission-denied, recycle-bin, bitdefender

My bitdefender keeps alerting me about Mimikatz in the recycling bin. I cannot remove it. Recycling bin is empty. $Recycling.Bin is empty but rd /r /q c:$Recycle.Bin says access denied.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Contact Bitdefender tech support?  Also, app and OS usage questions belong at SuperUser.com